# amazon ses perl script not working with postfix

Tags: amazon-web-services

Gents, not able to get postfix working with SES.

I am able to send from local accounts, but via telnet localhost 25 ... I get the following:

```
Mar 14 19:25:52 localhost postfix/smtpd[6634]: B3CCF1EB807B: client=mail.mofodomain[127.0.0.1]
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/cleanup[6629]: B3CCF1EB807B: message-id=<20120315002552.B3CCF1EB807B@mail.blabla.com>
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/qmgr[6624]: B3CCF1EB807B: from=<boconnor@mofo.com>, size=418, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: connection established
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: master_notify: status 0
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: deliver_request_initial: send initial status
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr status = 0
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: flags
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: flags
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 3
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: queue_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: queue_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: active
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: queue_id
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: queue_id
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: B3CCF1EB807B
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: offset
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: offset
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 652
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: size
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: size
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 418
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: nexthop
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: encoding
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: encoding
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: sender
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: sender
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: boconnor@adamslifebrokerage.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: envelope_id
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: envelope_id
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: ret_flags
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: ret_flags
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 0
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: time
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: time
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: DDdhTwAAAACC7g0AAAAAABI3YU8AAAAAxI0DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: log_client_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: log_client_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: mail.mofodomain
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: log_client_address
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: log_client_address
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 127.0.0.1
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: log_protocol_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: log_protocol_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: SMTP
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: log_helo_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: log_helo_name
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: adamslifebrokerage.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: sasl_method
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: sasl_method
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: sasl_username
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: sasl_username
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: sasl_sender
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: sasl_sender
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: rewrite_context
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: rewrite_context
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: local
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: recipient_count
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: recipient_count
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 1
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: original_recipient
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: original_recipient
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: recipient
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: recipient
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: offset
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: offset
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 630
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: dsn_orig_rcpt
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: dsn_orig_rcpt
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: rfc822;mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: notify_flags
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: notify_flags
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute value: 0
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: aws-email socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: input attribute name: (end)
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: deliver_request_get: file active/B3CCF1EB807B
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: deliver_message: from <boconnor@blabla.com>
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  /usr/src/ses/bin/ses-send-email.pl
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  -r
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  -k
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  /usr/src/ses/bin/aws-credentials
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  -e
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  -f
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: const  boconnor@adamslifebrokerage.com
Mar 14 19:25:54 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: dict_eval: expand ${recipient} -> mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: connect to subsystem private/bounce
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr nrequest = 0
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr flags = 0
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr queue_id = B3CCF1EB807B
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr original_recipient = mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr recipient = mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr offset = 630
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr dsn_orig_rcpt = rfc822;mofodomain@gmail.com
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr notify_flags = 0
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr status = 5.3.0
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr diag_type = x-unix
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr diag_text = User name is missing: 'undisclosed-recipients:;'. 
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr mta_type = 
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr mta_mname = 
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr action = failed
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: send attr reason = Command died with status 1: "/usr/src/ses/bin/ses-send-email.pl". Command output: User name is missing: 'undisclosed-recipients:;'. 
Mar 14 19:25:55 localhost postfix/pipe[6631]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribu



aws-email  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe -v 
  flags=R user=boconnor argv=/usr/src/ses/bin/ses-send-email.pl -r -k /usr/src/ses/bin/aws-credentials -e https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -f known@towork.com ${recipient}
```

Comment: http://www.improvisedscience.org/notes/AWS_SES

Answer (score 0):

This is what the AWS folks recommended to solve my situation:
(https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89611&tstart=0)

> Hello,
>
> Honestly, it looks like Postfix is failing to substitute the recipient
>   email address for the ${recipient} variable. Can you add --verbose per
>   the documentation to get a little more debugging information from the
>   Perl scripts.
>
> Furthermore, since we now support STARTTLS, you may be able to avoid
>   this entirely by connecting Postfix to port 25 of our SMTP endpoint
>   and make your system much simpler to administrate. There's more
>   information here in our documentation.
>
> Thanks, and please let me know if that helps.
>
> Paolo
>   http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Scripts.SendingFormattedEmail.html
>   http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.html